# Graph vs. Chart

Tags: word-usage

That is such confusion (for me). I meet these words (graph, chart) and they seem to me to be equal. Because somewherew I meet one of them for the same, like if they come from different language (respectivelly, from different dialect of English - Brittish, American).

But I am not sure. Are both words really equal? Or are they being used for different types of *graphs*? I really don't know.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43027/whats-the-difference-between-a-graph-a-chart-and-a-plot/272682

Comment: Graphs tend to show relationships on two axes on a Cartesian plane while charts can be of many different varieties like bar charts, pie charts, linear charts, etc.  Unless you're referring to a specific type of chart, you can interchange graph and chart without much change in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing on my experience listening to how people speak English, it seems to me that in casual speech people will often use these two terms completely interchangeably, but from a more technical point of view, they're actually not quite the same. When I, personally, think of a graph, I usually think of something like the graph of a square root function from mathematics (it looks like a long line going all the way across the xy plane):

[image]

A chart, on the other hand (or a bar chart, to be more precise, if we're talking about it in the context of statistical sciences), is something that rather looks like this:

[image]

So, if you really want to make sense out of these two words, then when you hear somebody say *graph*, think of the graph of a mathematical function which typically looks like some sort of curved line. When you hear the word *chart*, think of a bar or pie chart that depicts statistical information using colored bars or pie slices. However, there is one particular type of chart called a line chart and those can look strikingly similar to graphs. It actually would be very difficult for the uninitiated to the field of statistics to tell them apart.

Answer (score 0):

I think that graphs are a subset of charts.

That is why bar charts are sometimes also known as bar graphs.

Charts include things like graphs, tables, maps, ect.

According to [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chart), a chart can be either ‘a sheet exhibiting information in tabular form’, ‘a graphical representation’ or a map whereas according to [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/graph), a graph is a ‘a diagram representing a system of connections or interrelations among two or more things by a number of distinctive dots, lines, bars, etc.’

Most of the time in colloquial speech, the two terms are used interchangeably though.